# Incompatibility with Sonar7.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-gerrit

- Jenkins version：2.204.3
- Sonarqube version：7.9.2
- sonar-gerrit plugin: 2.30

I meet a issue：starting Sonarqube 7.7 in the preview mode (`-Dsonar.analysis.mode=preview`) was removed, making it incompatible with the plugin.

How can I fix this issue without downgrading sonarqube version and upgrading Jenkins version?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to do the following procedure:

1. Execute the analysis (as usual)
2. Download the report using the REST API
3. Generate the sonar-report.json local report using a "jq" script
4. Call the Sonar-Gerrit plugin (as usual)

This is the command for steps 2 and 3:

```
curl --user USER:PASS --header 'Content-Type:application/json' --request GET "https://SONAR-SERVER/api/issues/search?componentKeys=PROJECT-KEY&branch=BRANCH&resolved=false" | jq -f sonar-report-builder.jq > sonar-report.json
```

You can find the sonar-report-builder.jq file used in step 3 and more information about this issue [here](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonar-report-json-is-this-file-still-available/5827/13).

Comment: Thanks.It works correctly.Maybe revert commit contains drop preview mode and rebuild sonar on 7.7+ can resolve this issue too.

Comment: I think it's better to forget about the preview mode and move on.

Comment: Em, you are right. Mode of preview is deprecated reasonably. But I'm curious why the plugin such as sonar-gerrit and sonar-gitlab have not been compatible with sonar7.7 until now